# Dynamic SOQL ERROR: invalid operator on id field

Tags: soql, error, dynamic-soql

I'm facing this problem while creating this query.

```
 String qry = 'select name, id, account__c from orders__c '+' where account__c LIKE \'%'+searchText+'%\'';
```

**searchText** is declared as **public string searchText{get;set;}**

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what your code is trying to do? The way it is at the moment it is trying to find any `Account` with the Id like `searchText`

Comment: Are you trying to look for orders where the Account Name field contains your search text? if so you could try something like

`String qry = 'select name, id, account__c,account__r.Id from orders__c '+' where account__r.Name LIKE \'%'+searchText+'%\'';`

Comment: yes @BarCotter I'm  trying to find Account Name field that is equal to search text?

Comment: do I have to add the Child Relationship Name after where clause?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `account__c LIKE \'%'+searchText+'%\'` it is the same as `account__r.Id LIKE \'%'+searchText+'%\'`. `LIKE` operators can not be used on `Id` fields, when the error that you are seeing:

> invalid operator on id field

If you only want to find Orders where the Account name is Like the searchText term then you need to do something like the following:

```
String qry = 'select name, id, Account__c, Account__r.Name from Orders__c'
                 + ' where Account__r.Name LIKE \'%'+searchText+'%\'';
```

Also be aware that you are open to a [SOQL Injection](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_SQL_Injection) attack using this code. You should consider using `escapeSingleQuotes` as shown below:

```
String qry = 'select name, id, Account__c, Account__r.Name from Orders__c'
                 + ' where Account__r.Name LIKE \'%'+ String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchText) +'%\'';
```

Comment: Hi! Is Account__r the  Child Relationship Name to account?

Comment: yes, `__r` fields are relationship fields to the other objects.

Comment: I added the name present on child object (not the child relation name) and then it worked! thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
 String qry = 'select name, id, account__c,account__r.name from orders__c '+' where account__r.name LIKE \'%'+searchText+'%\'';
```

We cannot  use the **Like** operator on the  Sobject __c, from what I can gather. We need some field there.

Comment: thnx amit! You answer is correct too.